# Is there $\epsilon > 0$ such that $P(x) = x^d - 1 + \epsilon\sum_{j=1}^{d-1}x^j$ has a single simple real root close to $1$?

Tags: polynomials, roots

I have seen this being used multiple times in some proofs, but I am not able to prove it and I can't find a proof of this statement.

So basically I'm asking if anyone got a source proving this (or even more general) statement.

Edit: $d$ should be odd and greater than $5$.

Comment: Your wording is somewhat vague. I suppose you mean that $P_{\epsilon}$ has a simple real root $x_{\epsilon}$ with $x_{\epsilon} \to 1$ when $\varepsilon \to 0$ ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Basically yes, but it is also important that for some $\epsilon > 0$, $x_{\epsilon}$ will be the only real root of $P_{\epsilon}$.

Comment: I get a form $$P(x) = \left(x^d -1\right)\left[1 -\epsilon\frac{1}{1-x}\right] -(1+\epsilon)$$ (assuming $|x| \neq 1$) which does not really omit the solution you have, but maybe you can move on with it.

Answer (score 3):

For any polynomial Q a number $x_0$ is a simple root if and only if $Q(x_0)=0$ and $Q'(x_0)\neq 0$.

Also recall that the zeros of a complex polynomial depend continuously on the coefficients.

Now let $P_\epsilon(x)=x^d-1 +\epsilon p(x)$, where $p$ is another polynomial. For $\epsilon=0$ this has 1 as a root. Thus, for small $\epsilon$ $P_\epsilon$ has a root $x_\epsilon$ close to 1. Moreover, 
\begin{equation}
P_\epsilon'(x_\epsilon)=dx_\epsilon^{d-1}-\epsilon p'(x_\epsilon),
\end{equation}
which for $\epsilon$ close to $0$ is close to $d$ and hence not $0$. Therefore, for $\epsilon$ close to $0$, $P_\epsilon$ has a simple root close to 1.

Answer (score 1):

"single real root close to $1$" might mean that there is only one real root, which is in fact close to $1$, or that there is only one real root in some neighborhood of $1$, possibly other real roots elsewhere.

For the second: You could use Rouche's theorem to show that if $\epsilon$ is small enough then there is exactly one complex root in $D(1,r)$. Since $P(\overline z)=\overline{P(z)}$ that root must be real.

(For the first: More or less the same argument shows that if $d$ is even and $\epsilon$ is small enough there are at least two  real roots (one close to $-1$.)

Comment: The first option is what I meant. And what about odd $d$? 

I will even edit the question that only $d$ odd should be considered. And also greater than $5$.